# How to link text from a function to the same webpage using document.getElementbyID('').innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, function, hyperlink, innerhtml

trying to link this information to the "Click here to see.." and have it display on the same page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function rhinoinfo(){
    document.getElementByID('defArea').innerHTML="";
    "There are five different species of rhinoceros. The name rhinoceros means  
    ‘nose horn’ and is often shortened to rhino. It comes from the Greek words  
    rhino (nose) and ceros (horn).White rhinoceros are the second largest land  
    mammal. Rhinos can grow to over 6 feet tall and more than 11 feet in length.  
    Rhinoceros have thick, sensitive skin. Source: Savetherhino.org";
  }
</script>


<p>Click here to see information about the rhino.</p>
</div>
<div id="defArea">
  <p></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please also include a demo fiddle of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few problems.

- You were setting the innerHTML to an empty string, not the string on the next line
- You had mistyped `document.getElementById` as `document.getElementByID`
- You were not setting a handler to call your code when the user clicked the p tag

Here's a working version http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/Ljf28/1/

```
// I added an ID to the p, so you can hookup the handler from JS
document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('defArea').innerHTML = "There are five different species of rhinoceros. The name rhinoceros means      ‘nose horn’ and is often shortened to rhino. It comes from the Greek words rhino (nose) and ceros (horn).White rhinoceros are the second largest land mammal. Rhinos can grow to over 6 feet tall and more than 11 feet in length. Rhinoceros have thick, sensitive skin. Source: Savetherhino.org";    
});
```

You were setting the innerHTML to an empty string, not the string on the next line. Of course, you also have to call `rhinoinfo()` when the user clicks the p.

Also,

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, when you click the click here part, you want that text to show up in the "defArea" part of the page.

You are very close. You just need to add a link to the page to make this happen.

```
<a href="#" onclick="functionName()">Click here</a>...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NUqdZ/

**Edit** Per the comments:

Other errors that I corrected without mentioning...

- The innerHTML syntax was incorrect. Should be: `innerHTML="INSERT TEXT HERE"` without the semicolon in between the two. That would end the statement and not insert the text into the div.
- Updated the jsfiddle to reflect changes suggested below
- its document.getElementById not getElementByID

Comment: If you're going to use a link, it should have a real `href` so it works when JS is disabled. You should also return false so the URL fragment is not updated. Lastly, you shouldn't suggest inline handlers to noobs, teach them a better way. There were other errors with it too that you didn't mention.

Answer (score 0):

Coupe of things were missing.
byID here byId. 'd' should be small and no onclick event was there. Below is the code

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function rhinoinfo(){
    document.getElementById('defArea').innerHTML = 
        "<P>There are five different species of rhinoceros. The name rhinoceros means  " +
        "'nose horn' and is often shortened to rhino. It comes from the Greek words " +
    "rhino (nose) and ceros (horn).White rhinoceros are the second largest land  " +
    "mammal. Rhinos can grow to over 6 feet tall and more than 11 feet in length.  " +
    "Rhinoceros have thick, sensitive skin. Source: Savetherhino.org</P>";
 }
</script>

<body>
<p onclick="javascript:rhinoinfo();">Click here to see information about the rhino.</p>
</div>
<div id="defArea">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```